# SQL gym with less workers per district

Tags: sql, count, max, minimum

I'm struggling to find how to make a specific query to a set of tables that I have on my local database.

```
CREATE TABLE Gym (
eid INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(127) UNIQUE,
district VARCHAR(127),
area INT);

CREATE TABLE Trainer (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(127),
birth_year INT,
year_credentials_expiry INT
);

CREATE TABLE Works (
eid INT,
id INT,
since INT,
FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES Gym (eid),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Trainer (id),
PRIMARY KEY (eid,id));
```

The question is the following: I have several gyms and there are some cases where two or more gyms are located on the same district. How can I know, by district, which is the gym with less trainers on it?
The only thing I managed to get is the number of trainers per gym. Considering that, I can only get the gym with the minimum trainers from all districts...

NOTE: I am NOT allowed to use subqueries (SELECT inside SELECT's; SELECT inside FROM's)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: look into group_by and probably also order_by and limit.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use subqueries?  Is this part of a homework assignment?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I managed to solve all the other questions but since this is the last one, it is a little bit more chalenging and I could really use some help

Comment: I, for one, do not see how you can do this in a single query with no subqueries or CTEs.  I could do it with a subquery in the `where` clause, if that is allowed.  Or, for a single district.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes it is. It's not only allowed inside the SELECT and the FROM clauses. Inside a WHERE there is no problem as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have subqueries in the `where` or `having` clauseclause, then you can approach it this way.

First look at your query that counts the number of trainers by district.

Now, write a query (using that as a subquery) that calculates the minimum number of trainers in a gym in a district.

Next, take your first query, add a having clause and correlate it to the second by district and number of trainers.

This does use a subquery in a subquery, but it is in the `having` clause.  I'm not writing the query for you, since you need to learn how to do that yourself.

By the way, if you have window/analytic functions there may be other solutions.